# Xcode / Swift | Use .addTarget and guard on a UIButton

Tags: swift, xcode, uibutton, guard

What I got so far, are different TextFields that have be filled out and also a simple button (used as checkButton) for accepting the terms of use. Now, I would like to write that the textFields have to be filled out and the Button has to be checked. 
For the button I chose that it changes the image based on if state config is "Default" or "Selected". I think there is a problem with the .addTarget in setupTargetsAreGiven function and the self.button_aGB.isSelected == true in guard. The last function is only the animation that changes the image when pressed.

```
func setupTargetsAreGiven() {
    self.textField_username.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkTargetsAreGiven), for: .editingChanged)
    self.textField_eMail.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkTargetsAreGiven),
        for: .editingChanged)
    self.textField_password.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkTargetsAreGiven), for: .editingChanged)
    self.textField_confirmPassword.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkTargetsAreGiven),
        for: .editingChanged)
    self.button_aGB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkTargetsAreGiven), for: .touchUpInside)
}

@objc func checkTargetsAreGiven(sender: Any) {

    self.textField_username.text = self.textField_username.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    self.textField_eMail.text = self.textField_eMail.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    self.textField_password.text = self.textField_password.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
    self.textField_confirmPassword.text = self.textField_confirmPassword.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    guard
        let username = self.textField_username.text, !username.isEmpty,
        let eMail = self.textField_eMail.text, !eMail.isEmpty,
        let password = self.textField_password.text, !password.isEmpty,
        let confirmPassword = self.textField_confirmPassword.text,
        password == confirmPassword,
        self.button_aGB.isSelected == true
        else
    {
        self.button_register.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.20, green:0.29, blue:0.37, alpha:1.0)
        return
    }
    self.button_register.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.10, green:0.74, blue:0.61, alpha:1.0)
    self.isAbleToContinue = true
}

@IBAction func checkBox_aGB_pressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
        sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.1, y: 0.1)
    }) { (success) in
        sender.isSelected = !sender.isSelected

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            sender.transform = .identity
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: May I ask for some clarifications? (1) What *exactly* is the issue? I get that you think it's something related to `addTarget`, but if I should copy/paste your posted code into a blank project, what should I expect? (2) You posted three functions, and state that the last is "only the animation". Yet, it's the only `IBAction` posted. Have you set breakpoints in *each* of these functions? Are the getting hit? (3) What the expected result? What result do you get?

Comment: @dfd Basically I would like to let the code check if every textField is filled with information (made by the guard) and also at the same time that the "checkButton" .isSelected... If i do this with a switch like: "self.switch_aGB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkTargetsAreGiven), for: .valueChanged)" and then in the guard "self.switch_aGB.isOn == true" everything works fine, but I really don't know what "for: ." to use in the first function in combination with which "guard" I could use to check which image is loaded in the button.

Comment: Ok, I think you are saying the issue is in `checkTargetsAreGiven`? (That's the only function with a guard statement in the code you posted. And if this is correct, you are saying you *have* working code but... well, that's where I'm confused. You say "everything works fine" yet you posted a question. So maybe let's start from the beginning, and keep things simple. You have (at least) two `UITextFields` that are "required" along with a single `UIButton` that needs to do something. This single button needs to do one of two things - "Default" or "selected"....

Comment: Maybe I'm oversimplifying. If so, correct me. In fact, one more bit of clarification - what calls `checkTargetsAreGiven(sender: Any)`? What's the `sender`?

Comment: @dfd Maybe you understand better if I explain the main goal to you step by step: I am creating a register window in which there are Textfields (username, email, password and repeatpassword). In addition there is a type of "confirm the terms of use"-button that has to be checked. For that, I set its type on custom and the state configs on "Default" and "Selected" each with a different image for the button (a green check symbol and an uncheck symbol). If I click on it the image changes everytime from one to another with a simple animation, see last func. Next up I'm going to answer your question

Comment: The first function gets called automatically in the viewDidLoad()-method. After that I add Targets to all the UIs that check the guard in the next func every time ".editingChanged". The only time the code does not do that or better call the func is when hitting the check/uncheck-button, surely because "for: .touchUpInside" isn't right. I am sure about that, because if the button has its checkimage, and after that I edit a Textfield (because only textfields call the func), everything works fine. I wrote sender: Any, because of that there are different senders like TextField and also the Button.

Comment: Honestly? I'd do it differently. Two buttons (at the bottom), "register/create" and "cancel", with separate actions/targets for each. Put as many text files along with a checkbox (terms of service?) as needed. Since you are using `UIKit` I can safely assume it's iOS - so no need for a tab order. Let the user decide that, they are used to it. In your "register/create" action check that everything is filled in and that the password fields match, and if not, handle it (usually it's done by a `UILabel` with red text. There's really no need to add targets to `UITextFields` in my opinion.